# Cannot convert ascii to utf-8 in python

Tags: python, encoding

I have polish word "wąż" which means "snake"

but I get it from webservice in ascii, so :

```
snake_in_polish_in_ascii="w\xc4\x85\xc5\xbc"
```

There are results of my trying:

```
print str(snake_in_polish_in_ascii) #this prints me w─ů┼╝

snake_in_polish_in_ascii.decode('utf-8')
print str(snake_in_polish_in_ascii) #this prints me w─ů┼╝ too
```

and this code:

```
print  str(snake_in_polish_in_ascii.encode('utf-8'))
```

raises exception:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc4 in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I'm using Wing Ide, at Windows Xp with polish culture.

At top of file I have:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

I can't find a way to resolve it. Why I can't get "wąż" in output?

Comment: On Mac OS X I get the correct output by simply printing the "w\xc4\x85\xc5\xbc" thing. Make sure your terminal supports unicode. You could also try `decode` instead of `encode` to convert the string into a `unicode` object.

Comment: You can't possibly be *actually* receiving that word in ASCII, as the second and third characters aren't representable in ASCII. It's likely that the web service is using UTF-8, but not guaranteed. Like Alex, I suspect a lot of your *display* issues are due to your terminal.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This expression:

```
snake_in_polish_in_ascii.decode('utf-8')
```

don't change the string in place try like this:

```
print snake_in_polish_in_ascii.decode('utf-8')
```

About the reason of why when you do `print snake_in_polish_in_ascii` you see `w─ů┼╝` is because your terminal use the cp852 encoding (Central and Eastern Europe) try like this to see:

```
>>> print snake_in_polish_in_ascii.decode("cp852")
w─ů┼╝
```

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> i="w\xc4\x85\xc5\xbc"
>>> print i.decode('utf-8')
wąż
```

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
snake_in_polish_in_ascii = 'w\xc4\x85\xc5\xbc'
print snake_in_polish_in_ascii.decode('cp1252').encode('utf-8')
```

Answer (score 0):

by default python source files are treated as encoded in UTF8 inspite of the fact that standard library of python only used ASCII